# Getting error in using TabHost

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have just made a sample code to use TabHost in Android but it is causing error

> Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'

I dont know where i am wrong!

Here's my LogCat,

```
01-10 11:13:42.700: D/AndroidRuntime(4062): Shutting down VM
01-10 11:13:42.710: W/dalvikvm(4062): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a591f8)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.irctcdemo/com.example.irctcdemo.TabBar}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a TabHost whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.tabhost'
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.TabActivity.onContentChanged(TabActivity.java:131)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at com.example.irctcdemo.TabBar.onCreate(TabBar.java:20)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-10 11:13:42.730: E/AndroidRuntime(4062):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

TabBar.java

```
TabHost tabHost;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);

      tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

      // Get TabHost Refference1
      tabHost = getTabHost();

      // Set TabChangeListener called when tab changed
      tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

      TabHost.TabSpec spec;
      Intent intent;

       /************* TAB1 ************/
      // Create  Intents to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
      intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);
      spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("")
                    .setContent(intent);

      //Add intent to tab
      tabHost.addTab(spec);

      /************* TAB2 ************/
      intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2Activity.class);
      spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("")
                    .setContent(intent);  
      tabHost.addTab(spec);

      // Set drawable images to tab
      //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab2);
      //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab3);

      // Set Tab1 as Default tab and change image   
      tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
      //tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab1_over);


   }
```

firstscreen.xml code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/tabhost">

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TabWidget 
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </FrameLayout>



   </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Comment: It seems that when you get the tabHost reference you overwrite the previous assignement to tabHost

Comment: tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost); no need for this line just use tabHost = getTabHost();.

Comment: @PadmaKumar: I have checked that case also but it causes same error

Comment: Have you specified `TabHost` in  `R.layout.firstscreen`

Comment: post your firstscreen.xml layout.

Comment: @PadmaKumar: ok posting..

Comment: @PadmaKumar: posted xml file.

Comment: Is this full XML?In this you are missing the closing Tag for `TabHost` add `</TabHost>` at the bottom of your layout. Id for Tabhost is `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` and for **TabWidget** `android:id="@android:id/tabs"` and for FrameLayout Id should be `android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"`

Comment: @user3110424: already added..just missed that in pasting here..

Comment: @Android try to change the id as i specified in your layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your activity should extend TabActivity not Activity.

```
public class irctcdemo extends TabActivity {
```

and just use

```
tabHost = getTabHost();
```

remove this

```
tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

and your Id should be `android:id="@android:id/tabhost"` for `TabHost` and 
`android:id="@android:id/tabs"` for `TabWidget`

Comment: I have already extends it through TabActivity and removed that line then also getting same error.

Comment: Is there any difference in both syntax ?

Comment: noting difference when you are extends TabActivity it will look for the android ids. if you extends Activity and you declared as your own id then you need to call for tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.my_tabhost_id);

Answer (score 0):

Give tabwidget Id as

```
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
```

and Frame Layout Id as

```
 android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
```

in your xml file.